# MongoDB Java: Finding objects in Mongo using QueryBuilder $in operator returns nothing

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I have a `JUnit rule` called as `MongoRule` looks like

```
public class MongoRule extends ExternalResource {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoRule.class);
    private final MongoService mongoService;

    public MongoRule() throws UnknownHostException {
        mongoService = new MongoService(getConfiguredHost(), getConfiguredPort(), getConfiguredDatabase());
    }

    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        LOGGER.info(" Setting up Mongo Database - " + getConfiguredDatabase());
    }

    @Override
    protected void after() {
        LOGGER.info("Shutting down the Mongo Database - " + getConfiguredDatabase());
        mongoService.getMongo().dropDatabase(getConfiguredDatabase());
    }

    @Nonnull
    public DB getDatabase() {
        return mongoService.getMongo().getDB(getConfiguredDatabase());
    }

    @Nonnull
    public Mongo getMongo() {
        return mongoService.getMongo();
    }

    @Nonnull
    public MongoService getMongoService() {
        return mongoService;
    }

    public static int getConfiguredPort() {
        return Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("com.db.port", "27017"));
    }

    @Nonnull
    public static String getConfiguredDatabase() {
        return System.getProperty("com.db.database", "database");
    }

    @Nonnull
    public static String getConfiguredHost() {
        return System.getProperty("com.db.host", "127.0.0.1");
    }
}
```

Then I try to insert some documents as following

```
 public static void saveInDatabase() {
        LOGGER.info("preparing database - saving some documents");
        mongoRule.getMongoService().putDocument(document1);
        mongoRule.getMongoService().putDocument(document2);
    }
```

Where `document1` and `document2` are valid `DBObject` documents. The schema looks like

```
{
    Id: 001
    date_created: 2012-10-31
    vars: {
      '1': {
           name: n1
           value:v1
       }
      '2': {
           name: n2
           value:v2
       }
      '3': {
           name: n3
           value:v3
       }

} 
{
    Id: 002
    date_created: 2012-10-30
    vars: {
      '1': {
           name: n4
           value:v4
       }
      '2': {
           name: n5
           value:v5
       }
      '3': {
           name: n6
           value:v6
       }

}
```

Now I try to query the collection and get these objects, so I do this

```
public static void getDocuments(List<String> documentIds) {
        BasicDBList docIds = new BasicDBList();
        for (String docId: documentIds) {
            docIds.add(new BasicDBObject().put("Id", docId));
        }
        DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("$in", docIds);
        DBCursor dbCursor = mongoRule.getDatabase().getCollection("mycollection").find(query);
        System.out.println(dbCursor == null);
        if (dbCursor != null) {
            while (dbCursor.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("object -  " + dbCursor.next());
            }
        }
    }
```

`mycollection` is the collection where all documents are persisted, this comes from an external service.
When I run this document I see following

```
preparing database - saving some documents
inserting document - DBProposal # document1
inserting document - DBProposal # document2
false
```

Which means `collection.find()` could not find these documents.

What is that I am not doing right here? How can I get the documents back?

I am very new to using `Java` with `Mongo` and used this [reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/9WqH7CRfwak) to construct the query

**UPDATE**
After changing the way query is constructed, I still don't see documents

```
public static void getDocuments(List<String> documentIds) {
            BasicDBList docIds = new BasicDBList();
            docIds.addAll(documentIds)
            DBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
            query.put("$in", docIds);
            DBCursor dbCursor = mongoRule.getDatabase().getCollection("mycollection").find(query);
            System.out.println(dbCursor == null);
            if (dbCursor != null) {
                while (dbCursor.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println("object -  " + dbCursor.next());
                }
            }
        }
```

and the collection Name is returned via

```
private static String getCollectionName(@Nonnull final DBObject dbObject) {
        return "mycollection";
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your `putDocument` code as well - just making sure the collection names are the same :)

Comment: Also ensure you are using a write concern at least SAFE or the writes might not have been committed to memory before the find is executing meaning it will not find any documents.

Comment: It's not a valid query. I'll post a response.

Comment: @christkv, yes the default write concern is WriteConcern.SAFE

Comment: @Ross, I added the code that returns collection name

Answer (score 10):

You are now doing the equivalent of :

```
db.col.find({$in:[{Id:id1}, {Id:id2}, ..., {Id:idN}]})
```

Which is not a valid query since you're not specifying what field to $in on. I'm assuming you want :

```
db.col.find({Id:{$in:[id1, id2, ..., idN]}})
```

Change your query construction code accordingly and you should be fine.

EDIT: Adding correct code :

```
public static void getDocuments(List<Integer> documentIds) {

            BasicDBList docIds = new BasicDBList();
            docIds.addAll(documentIds)
            DBObject inClause = new BasicDBObject("$in", docIds);
            DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("Id", inClause);
            DBCursor dbCursor = mongoRule.getDatabase().getCollection("mycollection").find(query);
            System.out.println(dbCursor == null);
            if (dbCursor != null) {
                while (dbCursor.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println("object -  " + dbCursor.next());
                }
            }
        }
```

Please note that this assumes "Id" is something other than "_id"

Comment: The code is still wrong. And add a sample document, your schema description is ambiguous.

Comment: I updated the schema, thank you for helping out, I am still not able to figure out how to do this correctly

Comment: Have you tried my code? It works provided you don't provide a list of String put Integer (your schema makes "Id" fields an Integer rather than a String).