# How to create query with ObjectIds using java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have set of ids like:

```
["51eae104c2e6b6c222ec3432", "51eae104c2e6b6c222ec3432", "51eae104c2e6b6c222ec3432"]
```

I need to find all documents using this set of ids.

```
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(); 
    BasicDBList list = new BasicDBList();
    ObjectId ob1 = new ObjectId("51eae100c2e6b6c222ec3431");
    ObjectId ob2 = new ObjectId("51eae100c2e6b6c222ec3432");
    list.add(ob1);
    list.add(ob2);
    query.append("_id", new BasicDBObject("$in", list));
```

This query can't find anything because it is same as

```
{ "_id" : { "$in" : [ { "$oid" : "51eae100c2e6b6c222ec3431"} , { "$oid" : "51eae100c2e6b6c222ec3432"}]}}
```

To find something it must be

```
{_id:{$in:[ObjectId("51eae100c2e6b6c222ec3431") , ObjectId("51eae104c2e6b6c222ec3432")]}}
```

but I don't know how to make `ObjectId("51eae100c2e6b6c222ec3431")` in list using java

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB Java: Finding objects in Mongo using QueryBuilder $in operator returns nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650970/mongodb-java-finding-objects-in-mongo-using-querybuilder-in-operator-returns-n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{ "$oid" : "51eae100c2e6b6c222ec3431"}` is the same as `ObjectId("51eae100c2e6b6c222ec3431")` just in a different format.

See this page for the different formats: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/

If the query is not finding any documents (and you are sure they are present in the collection) then there is some other issue.  I would double check the server(s) you are connecting to and the name of the database and collection first.

Rob.

Comment: I just checked from mongo shell, this query {_id:{$in:[ { "$oid" : "51ebf50bc2e66fa145ddaa30"} , { "$oid" : "51ebf510c2e66fa145ddaa31"}]}} doesn't return anything though documents with these oids  presented in the collection

Comment: The "shell mode" format is ObjectId("51eae100c2e6b6c222ec3431").  The Java Driver's JSON utility turns ObjectId's into the strict format { "$oid" : "51eae100c2e6b6c222ec3431"}.  Does the query work from Java?

Comment: Yes it works from java. Thank you. But another problem that query returns only one document instead of two.

Comment: Which one?  The Java or Shell?  If Java can you edit the question with what the code looks like to execute the query and consume the results?

Comment: It does not show how you are executing the query.  Just building the query document.

Comment: I did `db.collection.find(query);` where collection is name of my collection