# Query with parameter which is an array in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I have an array like this :

```
 Array<int> arr = [1,3,98,12,...]
```

and I want to get all documents having Id which belongs to that array

```
 db.collection.find({"key": arr})
```

It would be crazy to use

```
  for (int i=1; i<= arr.length(); i++)
  {
    db.collection.find({"key": i})
  }
```

Instead, please help me if you know an effective way. Thanks !

Comment: Since you tagged this as Java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650970/mongodb-java-finding-objects-in-mongo-using-querybuilder-in-operator-returns-n seems like a reasonable match using `$in`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `$in` operator.

```
db.collection.find({"key" : {"$in" : arr} })
```

The above query returns any document if its key is in arr.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `$in` operator as described in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/). Something like this should do the trick:

```
db.collection.find({ "key": { "$in" : arr} })
```